# Return results but where the specific agent does not return in the results I need a null referencing the agent number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a script whereby I am searching hundreds of Agent numbers for contacts and if no result returns I need a null in its place.

For example the below script will return

```
AgentNumber | Description | StartDate
------------------------------------------------
51702       | Terminal    | 1900-01-01 00:00:00
10676       | RAMA        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00
10585       | RAMA        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00
```

What I need is for the results to show is where there is no data in the table:

```
AgentNumber | Description | StartDate
------------------------------------------------
51702       | Terminal    | 1900-01-01 00:00:00
10676       | RAMA        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00
10585       | RAMA        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00
10001       | NULL        | NULL

SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 990
SELECT AgentNumber,description,startdate 
FROM dbsSupport.dbo.ContractsIreland2
WHERE AgentNumber IN (51702,10676,10585,10001)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server based on the `SET` variable.

The solution to your problem is a `LEFT JOIN`.  You can do it as:

```
SELECT v.AgentNumber, ci.description, ci.startdate 
FROM (VALUES (51702), (10676), (10585), (10001)
     ) v(AgentNumber)
     dbsSupport.dbo.ContractsIreland2 ci
     ON ci.AgentNumber = v.AgentNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch I am indeed using SQL Server. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for some kind of `look-up` table

```
select l.AgentNumber, c.description, c.startdate 
from ( select 51702 as AgentNumber union 
       select 10676 as AgentNumber union 
       select 10585 as AgentNumber union 
       select 10001 as AgentNumber) l left join dbsSupport.dbo.ContractsIreland2 c 
on c.AgentNumber = l.AgentNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Gave me exactly what I needed.

Comment: @ryall579... If you are working with `SQL Server` use `value 
 construct..`